# run external program in a loop with max time limit

Tags: python

I wish to have a python script that runs an external program in a loop sequentially.  I also want to limit each execution of the program to a max running time.  If it is exceeded, then kill the program. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: There isn't a question here. You also have shown no work into this. Show some code and rephrase, please.

Comment: "What is the best way to accomplish this?" <-- Sounds like a question to me.

Comment: "Use Python" <- Sounds like an answer to me.  But probably not the answer they wanted.  Hard to tell what answer they did want when the question is so short and vague.

Answer (score 4):

To run an external program from Python you'll normally want to use the [subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html).

You could "roll your own" subprocess handling using `os.fork()` and `os.execve()` (or one of its `exec*` cousins) ... with any file descriptor plumbing and signal handling magic you like.  However, the `subprocess.Popen()` function has implemented and exposed most of the features for what you'd want to do for you.

To arrange for the program to die after a given period of time you can have your Python script kill it after the timeout.  Naturally you'll want to check to see if the process has already completed before then.  Here's a dirt stupid example (using the `split` function from the [shlex module](http://docs.python.org/library/shlex.html) for additional readability:

```
from shlex import split as splitsh
import subprocess
import time

TIMEOUT=10
cmd = splitsh('/usr/bin/sleep 60')
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
time.sleep(TIMEOUT)
pstatus = proc.poll()
if pstatus is None:
    proc.kill()
# Could use os.kill() to send a specific signal
# such as HUP or TERM, check status again and 
# then resort to proc.kill() or os.kill() for
# SIGKILL only if necessary
```

As noted there are a few ways to kill your subprocess.  Note that I check for "`is None`" rather than testing `pstatus` for truth.  If your process completed with an exit value of zero (conventionally indicating that no error occurred) then a naïve test of the `proc.poll()` results would conflate that completion with the still running process status.

There are also a few ways to determine if sufficient time has passed.  In this example we sleep, which is somewhat silly if there's anything else we could be doing. That just leaves our Python process (the parent of your external program) laying about idle.

You could capture the start time using `time.time()` then launch your subprocess, then do other work (launch other subprocesses, for example) and check the time (perhaps in a loop of other activity) until your desired timeout has been exceeded.

If any of your other activity involves file or socket (network) operations then you'd want to consider using the [select module](http://docs.python.org/library/select.html) as a way to return a list of file descriptors which are readable, writable or ready with "exceptional" events.  The `select.select()` function also takes an optional "timeout" value.  A call to `select.select([],[],[],x)` is essentially the same as `time.sleep(x)` (in the case where we aren't providing any file descriptors for it to select among).

In lieu of `select.select()` it's also possible to use the [fcntl](http://docs.python.org/library/fcntl.html) module to set your file descriptor into a non-blocking mode and then use `os.read()` (NOT the normal file object `.read()` methods, but the lower level functionality from the [os module](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html)).  Again it's better to use the higher level interfaces where possible and only to resort to the lower level functions when you must.  (If you use non-blocking I/O then all your `os.read()` or similar operations must be done within exception handling blocks, since Python will represent the "-EWOULDBLOCK" condition as an OSError (exception) like:  "OSError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable" (Linux).  The precise number of the error might vary from one OS to another.  However, it should be portable (at least for POSIX systems) to use the `-EWOULDBLOCK` value from the [errno module](http://docs.python.org/library/errno.html).

(I realize I'm going down a rathole here, but information on how your program can do something useful while your child processes are running external programs is a natural extension of how to manage the timeouts for them).

Ugly details about non-blocking file I/O (including portability issues with MS Windows) have been discussed here in the past: [Stackoverflow: non-blocking read on a stream in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375427/non-blocking-read-on-a-stream-in-python)

As others have commented, it's better to provide more detailed questions and include short, focused snippets of code which show what effort you've already undertaken.  Usually you won't find people here inclined to write tutorials rather than answers.

Answer (score 1):

## If you are able to use Python 3.3

From [docs](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/subprocess.html),

subprocess.call(args, *, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, shell=False, **timeout**=None)

> > > subprocess.call(["ls", "-l"])
> > >       0
> > >
> > > subprocess.call("exit 1", shell=True)
> > >       1

Should do the trick.