# In Windows, Killing an application through Python

Tags: python

I am trying to kill external running applications like **Windows Paint**, a **.mp3** and similar programs through a python script.

I open the program through`os.startfile`. Any ideas how I can close the programs efficiently? I am using a Windows 7 machine.
I'd appreciate the help a lot! Thanks!

Comment: Seems like the top answer to this question would do what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780425/run-external-program-in-a-loop-with-max-time-limit

Comment: What if I don't want to go through the subprocess method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Python 2.7 [os.kill](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.kill) works on Windows.  You could find the PID using [this recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/303339/).

Comment: You're welcome.  I agree it is more complicated than I expected.

Answer (score 0):

Popen will let you kill an opened process, but that won't prompt to save files, etc.

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['notepad', 'tmp.txt'])
#later
p.kill()
```

Comment: Can I open non .exe files with `P.open` ?

Comment: I just tried and it doesn't look like it: WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Answer (score 0):

When you ask Windows to launch something with `os.startfile()`, you don't get a handle to the created process. This is because the underlying [`ShellExecute()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function does not return a handle to the created process. I believe this is because not all actions actually result in a process being created at all (for example with in-process COM servers or other esoteria).